# separate key-value pairs of dict with semi-colon

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to separate a dictionary with key-value pairs into a string that would look like the following:

```
'key1=value1;key2=value2; ...'
```

For example,

```
 data = {
    "amount": "12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  }

 console.log(Object.entries(cookies).map((keys, values) =>{console.log(`${keys}=${values}`)}).join(';'));
  console.log(Object.keys(cookies).map((keys, values) =>`${keys}=${values}`).join(';'));
```

Neither produce the expected output:

```
'amount=12185;job=GAPA;month=JANUARY;year=2010'
```

Comment: What JSON are you referring to?

Comment: `(keys, values)` that isn't the pattern of arguments that are passed to `map`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I believe I meant dict, I was using JSON so I got mixed with the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

```js
data = {
    "amount": "12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
};

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`).join(';');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

using a reducer:

```js
const data = {
  "amount": "12185",
  "job": "GAPA",
  "month": "JANUARY",
  "year": "2010"
};

const string = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((currentStr, [key, value]) => currentStr + `${key}=${value};`, "");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: The last semicolon is extra.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with your second approach

```
data = {
    "amount": "12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
}
console.log(Object.keys(data).map((keys, index) =>`${keys}=${data[keys]}`).join(';'))
```

The problem is you've used the method .map() in the wrong way, it's supposed to be (key, index), the second argument is the `index` not `value`, but in your case, you won't need it anyway

Please have a look at the syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {"amount":"12185","job":"GAPA","month": "JANUARY","year":"2010"}

const r = Object.entries(data).map(x=>x.join('=')).join(';')

console.log(r)
```